# Is there a terminating state in UPPAAL?

Tags: modeling, uppaal

How can I create a "terminating" state in UPPAAL? If there is no edge from a state the execution will stop with deadlock. If the state has a loop without any guard the execution has never stopped. What is the best way to stop the Simulator execution without deadlock (if there is)?

Comment: Surely the manual covers that?

Comment: I did not find the answer in the manual.

Comment: Then can you please update your question to say what you looked for in the manual? It's always a [good idea](/help/how-to-ask) to make sure that you mention what you already tried, including that you searched and what for, so that it's clear how detailed an answer needs to be when someone who might be able to answer sees your question.

Comment: Timed automata do not have designated terminal state, so the question starts with wrong assumptions. The simulator is meant for model validation. If the model contains a loop then the correct simulation will not terminate. Verification on the other hand, may terminate when the property of interest is proven (some state of interest is reached, or the verifier detects a loop, or verifier detects that the state space was searched exhaustively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't any specific terminating state. 
Check out the comments below the question for more details.